# jqGrid - toolbar/ navigator not show on IE 9?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a simple gird with a navigator (toolbar) as I given below; 
Firefox, Chrome is able to show the toolbar, however, my IE is not.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/grid.locale-en.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" ></script>     
</head>
<body>
    <table id="grid1">
    <div id="pager1"></div>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">     
        jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid({ 
        datatype: "local", 
        height: 250, 
        pager: '#pager1',
        colNames:['Inv No', 'Client','Notes','Checked?' ], 
        colModel:[ 
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sortable:false}, 
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100, sortable:false}, 
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}, 
        {name:'ind_checked',index:'ind_checked', width:100, sortable:false, align:'center', editable:true, 
            edittype:'checkbox', editoptions: { value:"Yes:No" },  formatter:'checkbox'}
        ],
        caption: "Testing" }
        ).navGrid('#pager1');

        var mydata = [ 
        {id:"1",name:"test1",note:"note1",ind_checked:"yes"}, 
        {id:"2",name:"test2",note:"note2",ind_checked:"No"}, 
        {id:"3",name:"test3",note:"note3",ind_checked:"No"}, 
        {id:"4",name:"test4",note:"note4",ind_checked:"yes"}, 
        {id:"5",name:"test5",note:"note5",ind_checked:"yes"}, 
        {id:"6",name:"test6",note:"note6",ind_checked:"No"}, 
        {id:"7",name:"test7",note:"note7",ind_checked:"No"}, 
        {id:"8",name:"test8",note:"note8",ind_checked:"yes"}, 
        {id:"9",name:"test9",note:"note9",ind_checked:"No"} ]
        ; 

        for(var i=0;i<mydata.length;i++) {
            jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm testing them with IE 9, jqGrid 4.3.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? any setting in IE gotta change? please advise me, thank you.

Comment: You have an error in the `for`-loop: change `<=` to `<`, but I don't think, that this causes the IE9 to fail. I have no problem with this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/AF2vS/) in IE8; I can't test with IE9.

Comment: @scessor, yes, have to be corrected to < in the for-loop. however, I still cannot get the toolbar appears in IE9. I will try to test on IE8 to see the result. thank you.

Comment: Ah, sorry, the toolbar also doesn't appears in IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pager-`div` has to be after not in the `table` ([documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apager#definition)):

```
<table id="grid1"></table>
<div id="pager1"></div>
```

Also try this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/AF2vS/1/).

Comment: my bad, I'm too lazy to read all the words. @scessor, thank you very much!